# Check if a picture is shift of another

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, c++11

I have two images( of same size ) and I want to check whether the second is the same as the first one but with some shift.So more formally I have two matrices A,B of same size and I want to check whether a submatrix of B occurs in A. But as this pictures are big(400x400) I need an efficient way to do so. Acceptable complexity would be O(n^3).Is there a way that can be done or should I make the images smaller ?:)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is known in the literature as "Two dimentional pattern matching" (hint: google it). 
Here is a paper that describes both optimal and naive algorithms:

[Fast two dimensional pattern matching](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.581&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Another popular term is "sub-matrix matching", but this is usually used when you want certain level of fuzziness instead of exact matches. Here is an example for such algorithm:

[Partial shape recognition by sub-matrix matching for partial matching guided image labeling](http://people.rit.edu/esseee/docs/02.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use run-of-the-mill 2D cross correlation and detect where the maximum value lies to determine the (x,y) offset. Following the [Cross-correlation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cross-CorrelationTheorem.html) you can efficiently implement this in the Fourier domain.

See this simple example in Matlab on github, [cross correlation](https://github.com/mdiephuis/sandbox/blob/master/so/m_xcorr2.m) and [peak finding](https://github.com/mdiephuis/sandbox/blob/master/so/m_translation_offset.m)

EDIT

Here follows the short and mostly incomplete guide to the *rigid registration* of images. The gist of the cross correlation idea is as follows:
Say I have a 1D vector:

`t = [1 2 3 1 2 3 4 ]`

I shift this vector -4 places resulting in a new vector `t2`:

`t2 = [2 3 4 1 2 3 1]`

Now I have a look at the so called cross correlation `c` between `t` and `t2`:

`c = [1 5 11 15 17 25 38 37 28 24 29 18 8]`

Now, this cross correlation vector has a maximum of `38` located on position or index `7`. This we can use to ascertain the shift as follows:

`offset = round((7-(length(c)+1))/2)`

`offset = -4`

where `length()` gives the dimensionality or number of elements in this dimension, of the cross correlation result.

Now, as should be evident, the cross correlation in the Spacial domain requires a lot of operations. This is where the above mentioned [cross-correlation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cross-CorrelationTheorem.html) comes in to play which links correlation in the Spacial domain to multiplication in the Fourier domain. The fourier transform is blessed with a number of very fast implementations (FFT) requiring vastly less operations, hence the reason they are used for determining the cross correlation.

There are many methods that deal with so-called rigid registration from stitching of satellite and holiday images a like to overlaying images from different sources as often found in medical imaging applications.

In your particular case, you might want to have a look at [Phase correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation). Also the [Numercial recipes in c book](http://www.nr.com/oldverswitcher.html) contains a chapter on fourier and correlation.

Comment: Can't you explain a little more in details, and in pseudo code maybe coz I don't know much of Matlab.

Comment: In some implementations correlation is run on an image pyramid, starting with the smallest images and working up to full resolution. A match at 1/4 scale can identify the likely region(s) of best fit, then at successfully larger scales one finds a more accurate fit.